# slicing a list for list comprehension but keeping sliced values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, slice

I would like to replace `items[1]`, `items[2]`, `items[3]` with a boolean value based on whether or not the value is None. This works but eliminates `items[0]`, `items[4]`, `items[5]` from the output. I could insert/append the values back in, but I'm thinking there must be a way to do it in a single line.

```
my_list = [[10,30,None,20,30,40],[10,20,None,10,30,40]]
booleans = [[1 if item is None else 0 for item in each_list[1:-2]] for each_list in my_list]
print booleans
```

Expected Output:

```
[[10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40], [10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40]]
```

Comment: Just add expected output, for the sake of clarity

Comment: Note that you can assign to a slice; `each_list[1:-2] = [1 if item is None ...]`, although you'd have to unroll the list comprehension to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using nested list comprehensions:

```
booleans= [[l[0]]+[1 if i is None else 0 for i in l[1:4]]+l[4:] for l in my_list]
```

Answer (score 5):

You are close, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) when iterating over your inner lists and test whether the indices are in a set that should be modified. This allows you to easily modify which indices should be tested by simply modifying the `tests` set, and doesn't require some form of slicing which is difficult to modify easily.

```
my_list = [[10,30,None,20,30,40],[10,20,None,10,30,40]]
tests = {1, 2, 3}

new_list = [[v if i not in tests else 1 if v is None else 0 for i, v in enumerate(x)] 
            for x in my_list]

print(new_list)
# [[10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40], [10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40]]
```

Personally though, I wouldn't use a list comprehension in this case as it's *ugly*. The code below does exactly the same and is much more readable:

```
my_list = [[10,30,None,20,30,40],[10,20,None,10,30,40]]
tests = {1, 2, 3}

for x in my_list:
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if i in tests:
            x[i] = 1 if v is None else 0

print(my_list)
# [[10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40], [10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40]]
```

Comment: @Fsifegydd, what if the elements to be modified are defined via a `slice` object?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the rest of list (that you don't want to replace its elements ) to your edited sub_list :

```
>>> booleans = [each_list[0:1]+[1 if item is None else 0 for item in each_list[1:-2]]+each_list[4:] for each_list in my_list]
>>> print booleans
[[10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40], [10, 0, 1, 0, 30, 40]]
```